# No badge progress in Help Center -> Badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, help-center, badge-progress

When I enter Help Center -> Badges I would expect, or at least would be nice, if I could see my badge progress, just like now I see if I have the badge or not.

Comment: but badge progress is already shown in your profile, in the track next badge feature [at the left side under your reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6355709/asantacreu?tab=topactivity). No need to replicate that in the help center. And it would make that page rather expensive from a performance point of view as those pages can no longer be served from cache. Last but not least, you can use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=popular&q=badge+progress) to track most of your badges progress.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but when I opened the Help Center, I saw the badges I do have marked, and I expected to see the progress too. I just posted it because it was **what I expected to see**, but wasn't there.

Comment: @JonClements Was a feature request like this posted in the past?

Answer (score -3):

In badges (https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) the ones you already earned have a green tick on their left.

If you want a list of all your earned badges, go to your profile page, and on the right of your `next badge` click on the gear icon.

Comment: Yes, I know how to see the progress. I'm just saying that I expected to see it in the Help Center as well.